# Sql Sever Find Partial string in another string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
studentId        Classes
1               Auto CAD,Electronics
2               Instrumentation,Chemical,IT,English
3               Computer,Math,Hindi
4               Physics,Accountancy
5               Bengali,Geography
```

Now I want to search using single string "Instrumentation,Geography,Physics"

it will show the following

```
studentId        Classes
2               Instrumentation,Chemical,IT,English
4               Physics,Accountancy
5               Bengali,Geography
```

because studentid 2 contains Instrumentation, studentid 4 contains Physics and studentid 5 contains Geography

How can I do it using a `SELECT` statement ? not like Classes like '%Instrumentation%'
or like '%Geography%' or Classes like '%Physics%' because i want to use single variable to string "Instrumentation,Geography,Physics" or any combination of string separated by comma.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM    your_Table
WHERE   ','+Classes+',' like '%,Instrumentation,%'
OR      ','+Classes+',' like '%,Geography,%'
OR      ','+Classes+',' like '%,Physics,%'
```

I have added a comma with column as well as in the search criteria so that it will return only strings ending with commas

Answer (score 2):

You could use the T-SQL [Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) statement, but ideally you would normalize your database as you are not really supposed to have multiple values in the same field - for exactly this reason.

The *problem* with Like is that it can potentially match unwanted terms - a Like for %physics% would also match the 'astro-physics' course - which might not be what you want.

In Joe's example - adding commas will work (in this case) but this code is brittle (being a hack really) - if the opportunity is still there my recommendation would be to [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the database properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack your search string to a table variable and use in an exist clause.

```
declare @S varchar(500)
set @S = 'Instrumentation,Geography,Physics'

declare @T table(Class varchar(50))

while len(@S) > 0
begin
  insert into @T values(left(@S, charindex(',', @S+',')-1))
  set @S = stuff(@S, 1, charindex(',', @S+','), '')
end

select *
from YourTable as YT
where exists (
               select *
               from @T as T
               where ','+YT.Classes+',' like '%,'+T.Class+',%'
             )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd48d/1/0)